# FilteredTree throwing StackOverFlow Exception

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface, treeviewer

I am using a `FilteredTree` in my Eclipse plugin view inside a `SashForm` as follows:

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    Composite container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);

    container.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
    {

            SashForm sashForm = new SashForm(container, SWT.NONE);
            GridData gd = new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.FILL, false, true, 1, 1);
            gd.widthHint = 300;
            sashForm.setLayoutData(gd);
            {
                PatternFilter filter = new PatternFilter();
                FilteredTree tree = new FilteredTree(sashForm, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL
                        | SWT.V_SCROLL, filter, true);

            treeViewer = tree.getViewer();
            }

    }
    {
        browser = new Browser(container, SWT.NONE);
        browser.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 1, 1));

    }

    getSite().setSelectionProvider(treeViewer);
    getSite().getWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService().addSelectionListener(listener);

    createActions();
    initializeToolBar();
    initializeMenu();
}
```

Now whenever I use the `FilteredTree` to filter the contents of tree - it is throwing a `StackOverFlowError`. I am not able to figure out what is wrong with my implementation?

Exception :

```
!MESSAGE An internal error has occurred.
!STACK 0
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SendMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SendMessage(OS.java:3402)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.getItems(Tree.java:3304)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TreeItem.getItems(TreeItem.java:789)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.getChildren(TreeViewer.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalFindItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1823)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.doFindItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:903)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.findItems(StructuredViewer.java:810)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.findItem(StructuredViewer.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalGetWidgetToSelect(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1742)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalExpand(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1630)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalExpand(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1638)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalExpand(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1638)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalExpand(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1638)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalExpand(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1638)
```

Comment: Could you show us the full stack trace please

Comment: Added full stack trace

Comment: From the look of the trace it may be a loop in the tree structure.